# Has dialog's --checklist box type a possibility for horizontal srolling or \n (newline) interpretation?

Tags: bash, shell, dialog

I use dialog version: 1.3-20210324

**Given:**

```
LIST_ITEMS=(
  "1." "A ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext" "off"
  "2." "A ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext" "off"
                            ...                                     )
dialog ... --checklist "checklistName" 0 0 0 "${LIST_ITEMS[@]}"
```

**Result:** 
A classical dialog checklist with the *Informationtext* not visible entirely.

**Missing Goal:** 
I need a way to scroll horizontally or linewrap the *Informationtext*.

**Edit 1** 
@Thomas Dickey mentioned to reformat the data, that is no option for me because either way i do not have enough horizontal space. So as mentioned in my **missing Goal** section the real question remains. Anyways, thanks for your thought Thomas!
Any help is very welcome, thanks in advance!

**Edit 2: A Possible Solution** 
@LL3 gives two short examples on how to solve the problem. Thank you!

**Summary:** 
As of this edit date the current consent seems to be:

- `--check-list` has no horizontal scrolling option
- `--check-list` is intended to be a one-liner

Comment: You'd have to reformat the data.  That first column `"1."`, etc., is expected to be the short tag that's the focus of the user's attention.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Hi! Thakns for your thoughts. The short tag is just to keep the example simple. The tag in my cases will need a unavoidable explanation (the sometimes very very very long) Informationtext. Lets think about that as a unchangable fact. So and even so, if the tag gets longer it takes space for the Informationtext aswell, not much won :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the texts for checklist items in `dialog` are meant to be one-liner, and given that Thomas Dickey himself did not hinted differently I assume there's no way to tell `dialog` to handle `\n` escape sequences nor literal newlines embedded in those texts.

I can tell you how I handled quite easily cases like yours with either (or sometimes even both) of two convenient alternatives:

**If** your very very looong information text still fits in one single line of window, you can just add the `--item-help` option and provide an additional field for each item which would be the longer one-line text to show. That additional field would be shown at the bottom of the window when its respective field is the one where the cursor is positioned on.

So you would simply do something like below:

```bsh
LIST_ITEMS=(
   "1." "briefer text 1" "off" "A first ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext"
   "2." "briefer text 2" "off" "A second ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext"
)
dialog --item-help --checklist "checklistName" 0 0 0 "${LIST_ITEMS[@]}"
```

Note though that those additional fields are still meant to be single lines, and they also get automatically truncated by `dialog` if they don't fit in the window, just like the items's main texts do.

For truly long and/or multiline texts, it is easy to setup additional dialogs to be handled programmatically on request, like the below proof-of-concept for your example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash --
# Note it is conventional practice to use lowercase names for variables,
# whereas uppercase names are left to standards and to shell's own use.
list_items=(
   "1." "A ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext" "off"
   "2." "A ... very ... very ... looooong ... Informationtext" "off"
)
until choice=$(dialog --help-button --checklist "checklistName" 0 0 0 "${list_items[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty); do
    case $? in
    (1) btn=Cancel && break;;
    (2) case $choice in
        ("HELP 1.") dialog --msgbox 'this is a long explanation\nfor option 1.\n' 0 0;;
        ("HELP 2.") dialog --msgbox 'option 2 takes\neven three\nseparate lines.' 0 0;;
        esac
    esac
done
printf -- %s\\n "Pressed ${btn:-OK}"
```

HTH